# Converting SimpleDateFormat date format to Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Is there a generic way to convert the SimpleDateFormat date format to a regular expression in Java?

Comment: Could you give an example of what your looking for?

Comment: I would like to validate a date string but i can't use SimpleDateFormat because it is a part of a larger regular expression (and i don't what to do it in 2 parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing ready-to-use. And regex does not have knowledge about date constraints - for example what GMT is, or what am/pm is. For simplest cases you can use `\d{2}-\{2}-\d{4}` (`dd-MM-yyyy`), otherwise stick to `SimpleDateFormat` (or joda-time `DateTimeFormat`)

Answer (score 5):

For simple expressions you can just do

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
String regexFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("[mHsSdMy]", "\\d");
```

However to produce something which validates is far more complex. e.g. when MM=03, dd must be between 01 and 31, however when MM=02, dd must between 01 and 28 or 29 (depending on the year)

If you use MMM, DDD, ZZZ its much more complex and locale dependant.